# How do you configure a different journal folder for Perforce (Helix Core 2020.2)

Tags: perforce

I am running `p4d` on an Ubuntu instance in EC2. I have attached an extra EBS volume and it is mounted as `/opt/perforce-journals`. The server is called `master` and my `/etc/perforce/p4dctl.conf.d/master.conf` looks like this:

```
p4d master
{
    Owner    =  perforce
    Execute  =  /opt/perforce/sbin/p4d
    Umask    =  077

    Enabled  =  true

    Environment
    {
        P4ROOT    =     /opt/perforce/servers/master/root
        P4USER    =     supermodern
        P4JOURNAL =     /opt/perforce-journals/master
        P4SSLDIR  =     ssl
        PATH      =     /bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/perforce/bin:/opt/perforce/sbin

        MAINTENANCE = true
    }

}
```

However, the journal files are still ending up in `/opt/perforce/servers/master/journals`. What am I missing here?

Comment: Did you restart the server?  Are you sure that the p4d instance you're connecting to is the one started by this script?

Comment: I have restarted now, just to be sure. This is a vanilla installation, which is installed using `apt-get install -y helix-p4d`. Is there a way to check to journal location for a running server?

Comment: Found the command: `p4 configure show P4JOURNAL` and this is the output: ```P4JOURNAL=../journals/journal (configure)
P4JOURNAL=/opt/perforce-journals/master
P4JOURNAL=journal (default)``` When I try to change the configured value like this: `p4 configure set P4JOURNAL=/opt/perforce-journals/master` it says "Configuration variable 'P4JOURNAL' may not be changed."

Comment: Weird that the bad value is showing up as `(configure)` given that you aren't supposed to be able to use `p4 configure` to set it (and of course you also can't use it to unset it).  Do you have any recollection of where `../journals/journal` might have come from?  Some kind of setup script?

Comment: The solution I'd pursue at this point would be to check for the configurable in the checkpoint, and then manually generate a journal line to remove it -- this is a bit nontrivial if you haven't done it before so if you have a support contract I'd definitely recommend contacting Perforce for help.